# Arrow representing an event stopping a flow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

**Problematic**

I want to use `arrows.meta` to explain that an "event" (represented by `Rays`) stops the "flow" over time represented by the arrow. So far I almost get what I want but...

[image] [image]

... But how can I have

1. the part from Rays to Tee Barb `dotted` ?
2. the part from Rays to Tee Barb empty as in [VisualTikZ](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ-fr.pdf), p 22 (bottom of the page) ?
3. a **relative** placement (i.e. more precise alignment by percentage,equivalent to `midway` or `pos=.5`) of the Rays (rather than `sep=0.50cm` vs `line width=.1cm`).

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikz 
\draw[-{Tee Barb},line width=.1cm,blue] (0,0) - - (1.5,1) ;
\tikz
\draw[-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.50cm, orange] },line width=.1cm,blue] (0,0) - - (1.5,1) ;

%-------- position of Rays vary in cm, not in relative to
\tikz
\draw[-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.10cm, orange] },line width=.1cm,blue] (0,0) - - (1.5,1) ;
\tikz
\draw[-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.50cm, orange] },line width=.1cm,blue] (0,0) - - (1.5,1) ;
\tikz
\draw[-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.90cm, orange] },line width=.1cm,blue] (0,0) - - (1.5,1) ;

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second question is answered by "add a dot", so you need `-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.50cm, orange].Tee Barb}`. To address the first and third question, one can define a style with a preaction. This can be made one style using `\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared`. If the second argument has units, the solid line will be shorted by that distance. If it does not have units, the line will be drawn to the respective fraction of the line. Note that this counts the distance to the tip of the arrow head.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{event stopping/.style 2 args={decorate,
decoration={show path construction, 
moveto code={},
lineto code={
\draw[#1,dashed,-{Tee Barb}] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --  (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
\pgfmathparse{#2}%
\ifpgfmathunitsdeclared
\draw[#1,-{Rays[n=8,orange]},shorten >=#2] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) --  (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
\else
\draw[#1,-{Rays[n=8,orange]},shorten >=0pt] (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) 
 --  ($(\tikzinputsegmentfirst)!#2!(\tikzinputsegmentlast)$);
\fi
},
curveto code={},
closepath code={},
}}}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}
  \draw[-{Rays[n=8,sep=0.50cm, orange].Tee Barb},line width=.1cm,blue] 
   (0,0) -- (1.5,1);
 \end{scope}  
 \begin{scope}[xshift=2cm]
  \draw[event stopping={line width=.1cm,blue}{0.5cm}]  (0,0) -- (1.5,1);
 \end{scope}  
 \begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
  \draw[event stopping={line width=.1cm,blue}{0.6}]  (0,0) -- (1.5,1);
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @schrodingerscat Merci ! The `.` "dot" was totally unexpected :) 
Regarding the last question. I'd like to know if there is an equivalent to `midway` or `pos=.5` (i.e. more precise alignment by percentage) for position of the `Rays` on the arrow. I artificially do that here by saying it's 0.5cm vs a 1 cm arrow.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Thanks for the explanation. Yes, this makes sense. Luckily Ti*k*Z has a tool that allows one to check whether the argument has units, so we need only one style.